# what is NSZone? What are the advantages of using initWithZone:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There are so many functions like

```
1. NSDefaultMallocZone()
2. NSCreateZone();
3. NSRecycleZone();
4. NSSetZoneName();
5. NSZoneMalloc();
and many more related to NSZone
```

What does NSZone means, where to use these functions and when?
What are the advantages of initWithZone: and how to use in my iphone app?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> NSZone is Apple's way of optimizing
> object allocation and freeing. NSZone
> is not an object; it is an opaque
> C-struct storing information about how
> memory should be handled for a set of
> objects.
>
> One rarely needs to worry about
> handling your own zones in
> applications; Cocoa handles it
> transparently. A default NSZone is
> created on startup and all objects
> default to being allocated there. So
> why would you want to use your own?
>
> If you are mass-allocating hundreds of
> cheap objects, you may find the cost
> of actually allocating space for them
> becomes significant. Because the
> standard zone is used all the time, it
> can become very patchy; deleted
> objects can leave awkward gaps
> throughout memory. The allocator for
> the standard NSZone knows this, and it
> tries to fill these gaps in preference
> to grabbing more memory off the
> system, but this can be costly in time
> if the zone has grown quite large.
>
> If you want to mass-allocate objects,
> then, you can create your own zone and
> tell it not to bother with finding
> gaps to put new objects in. The
> allocator can now jump to the end of
> its allotted memory each time and
> quickly assign memory to your new
> objects, saving a lot of effort.
>
> Allocators can save you time
> elsewhere, too, as asking the OS for
> more memory, which a zone needs to do
> whenever it fills up, is another
> costly operation if it's done a lot.
> Much quicker is to ask for huge chunks
> of memory at a time, and you can tell
> your NSZone what to do here as well.
>
> Rumor has it that NSZone could save
> you deallocation time in the Good Old
> Days, too, with a method that simply
> chucks away all the allotted memory
> without bothering to call
> deallocators. If a set of objects is
> self-contained, this could save a lot
> of time, as you can chuck them all
> away at once without tediously
> deallocating them all. Alas, there
> appears to be no sign of this godsend
> in the current documentation; the
> single NSZone method (NSRecycleZone?)
> carefully puts all the objects in a
> zone neatly on the default NSZone. Not
> exactly a huge time-saver.
>
> So, in summary, zones save you time in
> mass allocations. But only if
> programmers know how to use them!

From [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZone)

Edit from comments: "Also important to note is that you can't use NSZone any more if you're using ARC. Which you should be."

Comment: Also important to note is that you can't use NSZone any more if you're using ARC. Which you should be.

Comment: @Adam, If you can add a citation too, I reckon that comment is worth adding to the answer.

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11 : "You cannot use memory zones. There is no need to use NSZone any more—they are ignored by the modern Objective-C runtime anyway." Foundation functions documentation indicates that zones are indeed ignore on iOS and 64bit OSX runtimes.